# XSL stylesheet Using variables to calculate

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

XML file:

```
<formattedEgGesamt>270.​94</formattedEgGesamt>
<formattedEgGesperrt>50.00</formattedEgGesperrt>
<formattedHgGesamt>78.18</formattedHgGesamt>
<formattedHgGesperrt>4.00</formattedHgGesperrt>
```

In my XSL file, I declare 4 variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="HGGesamt">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedHgGesamt,'#.00')"/>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:variable name="HGGesperrt">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedHgGesperrt,'#.00')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="EGGesamt">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedEgGesamt,'#.00')"/>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:variable name="EGGesperrt">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedEgGesperrt,'#.00')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

These variables are used to calculate the difference between formattedHgGesamt and formattedHgGesperrt, and formattedEgGesamt and formattedEgGesperrt.

The result should be printed.

Here's the code used to print the 2 results:

```
<fo:table-cell padding="3pt" display-align="center" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" border-color="white">
                        <fo:block font-family="Courier" text-align="right" font-weight="bold">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(exsl:node-set($HGGesamt)-exsl:node-set($HGGesperrt),'#.00')"/>&#160;&#8364;                             
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell padding="3pt" display-align="center" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" border-color="white">
                        <fo:block font-family="Courier" text-align="right" font-weight="bold">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(exsl:node-set($EGGesamt)-exsl:node-set($EGGesperrt),'#.00')"/>&#160;&#8364;                             
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
```

The result of the first lines of code, concerning HGGesamt and HGGesperrt are printed and the result is right.
For the EGGesamt-EGGesperrt, it only prints "NaN"

Does anybody have an idea, why?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a non-digit character with Unicode 8203 (U+200B, zero width space) in the data of `<formattedEgGesamt>270.​94</formattedEgGesamt>`,. after the decimal point. So that way the number computations result in NaN.

Answer (score 1):

As @martin-honnen said.

There's also easier ways to get the numbers that you want, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="HGGesamt" select="/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedHgGesamt"/>
<xsl:variable name="HGGesperrt" select="/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedHgGesperrt"/>
<xsl:variable name="EGGesamt" select="/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedEgGesamt"/>
<xsl:variable name="EGGesperrt" select="/Basis/PersonenkontoDTO/formattedEgGesperrt"/>
```

and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($HGGesamt - $HGGesperrt,'#.00')"/>&#160;&#8364;
...
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($EGGesamt - $EGGesperrt,'#.00')"/>&#160;&#8364;
```